# Apply filter to ajax data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux to fetch data from my back end. I fetch the data from my smart component using:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces())
}
```

and my action:

```
export function fetchPlaces() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES"});
    let path = "/server/places"

    axios.get(path)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

and my reducer:

```
const reducer = (state={
  places: [],
  isFetching: false,
  error: null
}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PLACES" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: true }
    }
    case "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, error: action.payload }
    }
    case "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED" : {
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, places: action.payload }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Each place has a property called `good_for` and this is an array of strings.

I would now like to be able to filter the places via a tag (passed via a query string which is already in place) but I need to be able to do this straight after the places have been retrieved from the database.

How can I integrate this in the "Redux way"?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question

> I need to be able to do this straight after the places have been retrieved from the database

If that means the `data` is already on the `client` side `AFTER` you have fetched, then you can use `Array.filter()` method to do this. Like so:

```
// For example your "good_for" field contains the following

const good_for = [ 'place1', 'place2', 'place3' ];

good_for.filter(p => p === 'place2');
```

Hope this helps ^^,

Answer (score 0):

On the promise `then` after ajax request (`axios.get`), you can filter it first before dispatching to reducer.

Assuming that the places candidate from query string is called `goodPlaces` and in form of `array of string` ex: `var goodPlaces = ["germany","japan","russia"]` and we are using `var lo = require('lodash')`.

```
.then((response) => {
  var places = response.data;
  var filtered = lo.filter(places, p=> goodPlaces.indexOf(p) > -1);
  dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED", payload: filtered})
})
```

Of course the filtering logic and tools you use is flexible. You just need to do it before dispatching.